# UITextField custom background color when editing

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, swiftui

I'm trying to give a background color to a **UITextField** using SwiftUI since I'm trying to use some unique colours in my app to support both LightMode and DarkMode.

My colors are always defined as a ColorSet in the xcassets folder and this is the code I was using at first to achieve this background color.

```
TextField("Exam title", text: $title)
    .padding()
    .background(Color("cardBackground"))
    .cornerRadius(8)
```

This way I'm able to change the background color of the TextField **when I'm not using it**.
This is how's the outcome of this

[Correct Look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LO8nj.png)

The problem I'm facing is that as soon as I tap on the TextField it goes back to its default color (I think it is the default one) and I'm unable to change that.

[When editing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVqO0.png)

So what I did was creating a `UIViewRepresentable` implementation of the TextField, maybe that could have helped me much more than SwiftUI can do at this stage.

```
struct CustomUIKitTextField: UIViewRepresentable {

    @Binding var text: String
    var placeholder: String
    var backgroundColor: UIColor = .red

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<CustomUIKitTextField>) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField(frame: .zero)
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        textField.placeholder = placeholder
        textField.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        return textField
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<CustomUIKitTextField>) {
        uiView.text = text
        uiView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        uiView.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
        uiView.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> CustomUIKitTextField.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(parent: self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        var parent: CustomUIKitTextField

        init(parent: CustomUIKitTextField) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
            parent.text = textField.text ?? ""
        }

        func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
            print("Begin editing")
            textField.backgroundColor = .brown
        }

        func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
            print("Finished Editing")
        }

    }
}
```

I've tried something as you can see (there are some things to just debug stuff) but I'm not that much experienced in UIKit so I don't really know what is the best way to tackle this problem and out there there's not much about this kind of problem.

Have you faced something similar before? How can I solve this problem?

EDIT:

If this can help this is the view hierarchy when the TextField is in editing mode and the selected elements that puts itself in front of the TextField is a UIFieldEditor

[UIFieldEditor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fK8LW.png)

Comment: You first code snapshot with TextField just works fine with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4, and with standard color and with custom color from Assets catalog.

Comment: I do actually have a beta installed, but even the *stable* version of Xcode isn't previewing this correctly, does the color stay the same even if you click on it and type some text?

Answer (score 1):

first off, don't define background colour in SwiftUI:
`.background(Color("cardBackground"))` / remove this line of code

In the makeUIView method, setup a default background color, which is used, when user not tapping the textfield:

`textfield.backgroundColor = .systemGray`

Finally, use these methods in the Coordinator class to control background colour behaviour:

```
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        textField.backgroundColor = .red
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField, reason: UITextField.DidEndEditingReason) {
        textField.backgroundColor = .systemGray
    }
```